# Need correct if statement code for button that closes the searchView

Tags: android, searchview

I have a searchView in my app that when you click on the search icon it displays searchView and the <-- button closes searchView. The code for displaying the <-- button is...

```
 actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

[image]

What if statement would I need to code my <-- button so I can code what it does.

```
if(actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)) {}
```

The above code doesn't work. There is also no...

```
if(actionBar.onClick){}
```

I'm looking for an if statement that says if that <-- button is clicked on, close the searchView.

```
if(onBackPressed){}  //doesn't work either
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if(android.R.id.home == item.getItemId()){
            //write your code here
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: I figured this same code out 5 minutes after asking the question. Nevertheless, it is correct.